# from scipy.optimize._shgo_lib.sobol_seq import Sobol does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to use SMAC3 (https://automl.github.io/SMAC3/master/quickstart.html) to tune some hyperparameters. For that, I need to import `from smac.facade.smac_hpo_facade import SMAC4HPO` but this causes the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.optimize._shgo_lib.sobol_seq'`.

I'm working with conda and I've installed smac like described in the documentation. `scipy` is also installed properly. Does somebody have an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Which version of SciPy is installed?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have scipy 1.7 installed, just run
pip install --force-reinstall scipy==1.6

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command and restart the runtime - google colab

```
pip install --force-reinstall scipy==1.7.0
```

Comment: No, the function was removed with SciPy 1.7.